# Program continues when it should break

Tags: java, methods

I'm creating a program that asks users to input a username and password, checks whether it's the same as one of the three sets of usernames and passwords that I have, and continues with the program if it is. If it doesn't match any of the sets, it should ask the user to enter a username and password again. After three tries, it should exit the program. Right now, no matter what I enter in for the username and password, it will continue with the next part of the program. Here is the main code:

```
int y = 0;
do {
    String user = user(scan);
    String pass = pass(scan);
    boolean b = check(user, pass);
    if (b = false) {
        y+=1;
    } 
    if (y == 3) {
        System.out.println("Too many incorrect tries");
        break;
    }
} while (y != 0);
```

Here is the user method:

```
public static String user(Scanner scan) {
    System.out.print("Enter your username: ");
    String username = cipher(scan.nextLine(), 5);
    return username;
}
```

Here is the pass method:

```
public static String pass(Scanner scan) {
    System.out.print("Enter your password: ");
    String pass = cipher(scan.nextLine(), 5);
    return pass;
}
```

Here is the check method:

```
public static boolean check(String username, String password) {
    boolean valid = false;
    if (username.equals("Ofhp") && password.equals("ofhpnsjq8")) {
        valid = true;
    } else if (username.equals("Fqnhnf") && password.equals("nqtajofhp79")){
        valid = true;
    } else if (username.equals("Idqfs") && password.equals("hmzggdgzssd")) {
        valid = true;
    } else {
        valid = false;
    }
    return valid;
}
```

Comment: One problem i can see is use b==false instead of b=false in if condition inside do while loop

Comment: Also use System.exit() instead of break

Comment: @vinay not if there's code after that loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need a double equal sign here:

```
if (b = false) {
    y+=1;
}
```

EDIT: or simply

```
if(!b) {
```